# urlrewrite.net - Real Querystring Appended on PostBack

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6, url-rewriting

I'm using urlrewrite.net to build friendlier urls, and have the following rewrite rule in my web.config:

```
<if url="^/forsale/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)">
 <rewrite to="/aircraft/result.aspx?view=$2&amp;cat=$3&amp;loc=$4&amp;model=$5" />
</if>
```

This means I can now browse to:
http://www.mydomain.com/dept/manufacturer/,734,,810,,159,,163,,,,,,,,/1/999999/false

to view the actual url of:
http://www.mydomain.com/folder/result.apsx?view=,734,,810,,159,,163,,,,,,,,/1/999999/false?view=,734,,810,,159,,163,,,,,,,,&cat=1&loc=999999&model=false

This works fine until I trigger any sort of PostBack event(button click etc), at which point the real page's querystring is added to the end of the rewrite url eg:

http://www.mydomain.com/dept/manufacturer/,734,,810,,159,,163,,,,,,,,/1/999999/false?view=,734,,810,,159,,163,,,,,,,,&cat=1&loc=999999&model=false

Any help / suggestions / answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET in .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 provides a very simple way to fix that. Now you can use the property of the HtmlForm class called Action to set the postback URL to the one that was requested by browser before any rewriting happened. In ASP.NET you can obtain that URL by using HttpRequest.RawUrl property. So, to fix the postback URL for your web form when you use URL Rewrite Module, you would need to add the following code to the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;  
}
```

Check Here for detail:

[ASP.NET postbacks and URL rewriting](http://ruslany.net/2008/10/aspnet-postbacks-and-url-rewriting/)

Also, check this:

**Handling ASP.NET PostBacks with URL Rewriting**:

With ASP.NET 2.0, there is a cleaner trick that you can use to rewrite the "action" attribute on the  control.  Specifically, you can take advantage of the new ASP.NET 2.0 Control Adapter extensibility architecture to customize the rendering of the  control, and override its "action" attribute value with a value you provide.  This doesn't require you to change any code in your .aspx pages.  Instead, just add a .browser file to your /app_browsers folder that registers a Control Adapter class to use to output the new "action" attribute:

Check Here for detail:

[Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) :

Comment: I actually found this yesterday and had just returned here to update / answer my question. Technically I beat you too it, but ill mark yours as the correct answer. Thanks for taking the time to respond, its really appreciated.